# ACF Wordpress Group with Repeater inside a Repeater

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i have a Repeater and in that Repeater is a Group and inside this Group is another Repeater.
Now i want to get the values from the Repeater inside the Group.

This is my Structure:

```
-partner (repeater)

--info (group)
---logo
---headline
---subline
---description
---facts (repeater)
----fact
```

And this is how my Code Kinda looks like:

```
<?php 
$partner = get_sub_field('partner');
?>

<div>
    <?php while( have_rows('partner')): the_row();
    $info = get_sub_field('info);
    ?>

    Here is some output of the Group $info that works perfectly..

        <?php while( have_rows('info')): the_row(); ?>
            <?php while(have_rows('facts')): the_row();
            $fact = get_sub_field('fact');
                <?php print_r($fact) ?> <--- No outcome!
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Already searched the Web.. that was the stuff i kinda found.. but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your `PHP` code to correctly loop through the fields. First, I used a foreach loop to iterate over the top-level '`partner`' repeater field. Within each '`partner`' item, I accessed the '`info`' group and extracted its fields. Then, another `foreach` loop was used to iterate over the 'facts' repeater field inside the 'info' group.
Try this

```
<?php 
$partners = get_field('partner');  
if($partners):
    foreach($partners as $partner):
        $info = $partner['info'];  // 'info' is a group inside the 'partner' repeater

        // Output some fields from the 'info' group
        echo $info['headline'];
        echo $info['subline'];
        // ... other fields from 'info'

        // Now loop through 'facts' repeater inside 'info' group
        if($info['facts']):
            foreach($info['facts'] as $fact):
                echo $fact['fact'];  // Output the 'fact' field inside the 'facts' repeater
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
?>

<div>
    <!-- Your HTML and output here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved it my self already.. but i did it with 4 loops into another your Solutions is way better.